# Mod Rewrite SEO urls and R=301

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect

I want my URL to look like as following and also inform search engines the URL has permanently changed.

```
www.example/shop/12/title
```

I achieved this by using the following

```
RewriteRule ^shop/([^/]*)/([^/]*)$ /shop.php?prod=$1 [L]
```

but, I'm stuck on the Permanent Redirect URL.

When I try the following

```
RewriteRule ^shop/([^/]*)/([^/]*)$ /shop.php?prod=$1 [R=301,L]
```

Links like *www.example/shop/12/title* are redirected to *www.example/shop.php?prod=12*

This should stay as the seo friendly link.

Any Help?

Comment: So old URLs are: `www.example/shop.php?prod=12` and new URLs are: like `www.example/shop/12/title`??

Comment: Hi, yes that is correct

Comment: Then rules cannot help since rules cannot pull `title` from your database. At best rules can redirect to `www.example/shop/12/`

Comment: No the links actually work, the links are generated by the shop. so the link e.g. www.example/shop/12/large_shirt calls the URL www.example/shop.php?prod=12. Its the R=301 causing an Internal Error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since your new urls contain a title that is not in your original 'ugly' urls, you cannot redirect from within mod_rewrite. It is not possible to summon information from thin air in mod_rewrite.

The best you can do is adding the following in the top of shop.php:

```
if( strpos( $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'], "shop.php" ) !== FALSE ) {
  $id = $_GET['prod'];
  $title = getTitleById( $id );
  header( "Location: /shop/{$id}/{$title}", TRUE, 301 );
  exit();
}
```

Comment: But the links actually work, the links are generated by the shop. e.g. www.example/shop/12/large_shirt calls the URL www.example/shop.php?prod=12. Its the R=301 causing an Internal Error.

Comment: You want to redirect /shop.php?prod=12 to /shop/12/title-of-something. That is impossible, because "title-of-something" is not in the url.